# Retrofit2, Different behaviour for Debug and Release Build

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my Android-App I use retrofit2 to handle some HTTPS-Requests. One of them is a login endpoint. If I compile my App with the Debug buildtype, everything is working as expected

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://...sign_in/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 45
D/OkHttp: Cookie: 
D/OkHttp: {"email":"...","password":"..."}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (45-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://.../sign_in/ (650ms)
D/OkHttp: cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 06:55:17 GMT
D/OkHttp: server: Cowboy
D/OkHttp: set-cookie: _backend_key=...; path=/; HttpOnly
D/OkHttp: x-request-id: ...
D/OkHttp: content-length: 52
D/OkHttp: {"data":{"user":{"email":"...","id":2}}}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (52-byte body)
```

If i compile it with the Release buildtype, the body is not attached to my request

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://.../sign_in/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2
D/OkHttp: Cookie: 
D/OkHttp: {}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (2-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 500 https://.../sign_in/ (268ms)
D/OkHttp: cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 06:51:12 GMT
D/OkHttp: server: Cowboy
D/OkHttp: content-length: 45
D/OkHttp: {"errors":{"detail":"Internal Server Error"}}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (45-byte body)
```

It worked before I updated to Android 10. So I can only think, that this might be the reason, but actually it doesn't make sense to me.

I use retrofit 2.5.0

Comment: Your request body is empty in release_build_type, have to take a look of your code.

Comment: just guessing in release mode do you use proguard and do you have rules fro your pojos?

Comment: Show us a bit the POJO you use for the body. If you have proguard, I might have a guess that you didn't annotate the fields properly

Comment: Looks like proguard is obfuscating the class members of your request body class.

Comment: Seems like. I hadn't this issue with my last release. I added now some Proguard-Rules I found here: https://medium.com/@abangkis/retrofit-2-and-the-three-body-problem-f8a93039aeb2
and added my POJO with the Login-Credentials. I also annotated my fields with @SerializedName(). So I can no login. But I have now other problems, which I hasn't before ....

Comment: can you post your response object?

Comment: Hey @hasan_shaikh in my initial post I posted the request and response. I found a solution for the problem, it was not retrofit but ProGuard who caused a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I found the issue. I never had it before but now I have it. ProGuard is doing some things that I didn't expected. This site was a good starting point to figure it out https://medium.com/@abangkis/retrofit-2-and-the-three-body-problem-f8a93039aeb2 .
I disabled for now the minify process in my gradle file. I guess it will take a while to figure everything out. If I keep it active it more or less destroys some functionality of my App :)